# Cannot open existing Laravel project in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, phpstorm

I started learning Laravel today and I installed it successfully. Created a new project from shell as the Laracast tutorial.

When I tried to open the project in PhpStorm like I am used to do in Symfony framework, the program start with an empty screen like this:

[image]

If I open the program normally and chose open project from existing files, I browse to the location and open, it does nothing and return to welcome screen.

Symfony projects are working fine and Laravel projects are opening normally on VSCode.

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Did you open the entire laravel installation folder? It should be indexing which can take some time in PHPStorm.

Comment: Please check your `idea.log` for possible hints (Help | Show Log in...). It's possible that you have some "misbehaving" plugin that leads to this. If that's so -- please try with disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins and see how it will behave this time. Clearing caches may also be useful (after doing previous steps).

Comment: @Option You mean my project root folder ? then yes - All I did was "laravel new blog" and then tried to open it

Comment: @LazyOne please clarify where can I find idea.log file

Comment: @Sherbieny It's there -- in my comment. Just few words after `idea.log`

Comment: Do you have the project view open?  It's Cmd+1 on the mac, not sure about Ubuntu.  In the View > Tool Windows menu, you should be able to toggle Project on and off.

Comment: So .. did you managed to have it working? If not -- can you share your idea.log file?

Comment: Don't know what changed, but I can now open the project :D - I really have no idea what changed, I left the project for a couple of days and now it opens